# HTML "capture" attribute for desktop computer/pc

Tags: python, html, django, image, capture

I'm making a web app using Django that requests images from users and processes them. When I use the following code:

```
<label for="imageFile">Upload a photo:</label>
<input type="file" id="imageFile" capture="user" accept="image/*">
```

I don't get an option to take a photo from the laptop's camera. Several websites said that the capture attribute might not work for desktop computers and I don't know what I should use instead.

This is my code

HTML:

```
{% extends "image/layout.html" %}
{% load static %}


{% block body %}   

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="file" name="image" accept="image/*" capture="user">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
    
{% endblock %}
```

Views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import *

def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        img = request.POST['img']
        #save image in model
        return render(request, 'image/image.html')
    else:
        return render(request, 'image/image.html')
```

I haven't implemented the procedure to save the image yet.

Comment: Can you please try the following: `<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera">`

Comment: if you are using forms use this inside your form tag: enctype="multipart/form-data"

Comment: @amadousow I used it but it didn't work

Comment: @AhmedAblak I used it as well but it didn't work either

Comment: show us your template please and your views.py that process that form.

Comment: @amadousow I have added it to my question